# Bandwidth vs Uplink Port Speed

Tags: dedicated-server, network-speed

If a dedicated server has -
1. 1Gbps uplink port speed 
2. 1Mbps unmetered bandwidth

Under what circumstances will bandwidth be a limiting factor for serving requests and under what circumstances will the uplink port speed be a limiting factor for serving requests? 
 
What is the difference between bandwidth and uplink port speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about paying monthly for a dedicated server that someone else hosts. The 1Gbps uplink port is the limit of the server. The 1Mbps is what they are limiting you to out of that 1Gbps. You could pay them for more bandwidth, up to a limit of 1Gbps.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between bandwidth and uplink port speed?

Uplink port speed is the physical connection between your server's network card (whether physical or virtual) and the switch it's connected to. The port speed has precious little to do with how much bandwidth is available to your server other than setting a top bound on that number.

In your case, your allotted bandwidth is 1Mbps, so that will be your limiting factor.